# glFrustum() in OpenGL ES: why do shapes appear the same size?

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to understand the perspective view in OpenGL.
What I am trying to do is render two identical triangles, but at different z coordinates, so I assume they should appear at different sizes. Here is my code:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX Vertices[] =
{
    { 0.5f,  1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // x, y, z, color
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
};
```

and for drawing

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0, 3);
glTranslatef(0.0f,-1.0f,-1.5f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0, 3);
```

and here is how I init some attributes

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearDepthf(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustumf(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                   
glLoadIdentity();
```

but the triangles appear at the same size, just at different locations as I translated  Y.
Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use 0.0 for the perspective projection's near-Z value. It must be a positive number greater than zero. Preferably on the order of 1.0 or so.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicol said you should use numbers greater than 0 for frustrum construction. I strongly suggest you to read this [article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) to understand why it is so.